# Dynamic Population of Popup Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have multiple button like elements that opens up a single modal popup. I am try to populate it dynamically according to the element that is used to open the modal. I am using JSP and servlets.I would also like to know about sending parameters to the click function.

```
$('.btn-primary').bind('click', function(event) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
});

<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="z-index:4">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <span class="close">×</span>
                       <h4>Submitted List</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  </div>
               </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what version of jquery do you use?

Comment: i don't see any function named click in your code

Comment: 1.11.3.. Why does version of Jquery matter?, If i may ask.

Comment: $('.btn-primary').bind('click', function(event) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    });

it is a click function

Comment: bind is depreciated since 1.7

Comment: @madalinivascu okay.thanks for that info. But you havent still clarified my basic doubt (how to dynamically populate the modal box--JSP and servlet solutions only).

Answer (score 2):

Use data attributes to pass the data

```
<button class="btn-primary" data-content="this will be displayed in the modal body">
$('.btn-primary').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).attr('data-content');
    $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').html(content);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

or use ajax by passing a id to the servlet

```
  <button class="btn-primary" data-id="1">
  $('.btn-primary').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id= $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({url:'path/to/servlet',data:{id:id},success:function(data){
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').html(data);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }})

    });
```

Comment: I wanted something like running a servlet and fetching data as soon as I pass an attribute through onclick() and displaying the dynamically fetched data onto the modal.

Comment: you mean you want to use ajax

Comment: I have no clue about ajax technology.Could you guide me through it?