# Display contents of $row in a modal dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I have a website in which events are queried and displayed on the index page. Upon clicking an image which was among the results of the query, a modal pops up.

As i have multiple images, I would like to dynamically display the contents of each row in the modal depending on which image was clicked. Currently, I am able to click any image and a modal appears, however they all contain the data from row[0].

INDEX PAGE:

```
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        include 'testModal.php';
        echo "<tr><td><figure><figcaption style='padding-bottom:20px'>" . $row["name"]."</figcaption>".
        '<img class="modalBtn" style="width:15em; height:17em;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/></figure></td>'.
            "<td>".$row["category"]."</td>".
            "<td> $".$row["price"]."</td>".
            "<td>".$row["age"]."</td>".
            "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
```

The below is the modal page.

MODAL PAGE:

```
<div id="TheModalTest" class="modal">

<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeWindow()">X</span>
</div>
<div>
   <?php echo '<img style="width:15em; height:17em;" 
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>'; ?>
</div>
 <?php  echo '<p class="desc">'.$row["description"].'</p>' ?>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>BOOK NOW</h3>
</div>
</div>    
</div>
      <script>
          //get modal
          var Testmodal = document.getElementById('TheModalTest');
          //get button that opens modal
          //var modalbtn = document.getElementById('modalbtn');
          var modalbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('modalBtn');
          console.log("Length: " + modalbtn.length);
          //Open modal when btn click
          for (var i = 0; i < modalbtn.length+1; i++ ) {
              console.log("I IS: " + i);

                 modalbtn[i].onclick = function(){
                console.log("MODAL IS: " + modalbtn[i]);
              Testmodal.style.display = "block";

          }
    }

      </script>
```

The below images are what it looks like. When i click the event image for Kanye, the modal pops up with his image. However if i click the image of Katy Perry, the modal pops up with Kanye still.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly6k1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTadY.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Population of Popup Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181838/dynamic-population-of-popup-modal)

Comment: Try not to mix `"` and `'`. Just stick with single quotes for php and js, it makes it simpler when you're starting. What you'll need to do is add an attribute to the element with the data you want to pass to the modal, than grab that attribute's value with your js.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question Something unclear, Try to Provide the Output screenshots and mark it. Because i don't know the output.
But

**I have Re written your mysql Code as foreach So you can play with foreach images.**

```
while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
foreach($row1 as $row){
include 'testModal.php';
echo "<tr><td><figure><figcaption style='padding-bottom:20px'>" . $row["name"]."</figcaption>".
'<img class="modalBtn" style="width:15em; height:17em;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/></figure></td>'.
    "<td>".$row["category"]."</td>".
    "<td> $".$row["price"]."</td>".
    "<td>".$row["age"]."</td>".
    "</tr>";
}
}
```

Replace the above code with your Old one. Hope it works.

Comment: Updated with images

Comment: @PeterJ the 2 screenshots are showing fine. 1 screenshot is showing grabbing from all images, and another one is popup modal image view with close option working right? so what was the issue?

Comment: So the Modal that pops up, notice how the image is of Kanye, that is always the image, regardless if i click on another event (Katy Perry for example). I would like it so that if i click on Katy Perry, it should be the image of her instead of Kanye

Answer (score 0):

Try not to mix " and '. Just stick with single quotes for php and js, it makes it simpler when you're starting.

What you'll need to do is add an attribute to the element with the data you want to pass to the modal, than grab that attribute's value with your js.

notice: `data-category="'.$row['category'].'"` below

```
<?
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    include 'testModal.php';
    echo '<tr><td><figure><figcaption style="padding-bottom:20px">' . $row['name'].'</figcaption>'.
        '<img data-category="'.$row['category'].'" class="modalBtn" style="width:15em; height:17em;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/></figure></td>'.
        '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>'.
        '<td> $'.$row['price'].'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$row['age'].'</td>'.
        '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

now in the modal... notice `category = modalbtn[i].getAttribute('data-category');`

```
<div id="TheModalTest" class="modal">

<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeWindow()">X</span>
</div>
<div>
   <?php echo '<img style="width:15em; height:17em;" 
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>'; ?>
</div>
 <?php  echo '<p class="desc">'.$row["description"].'</p>' ?>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>BOOK NOW</h3>
</div>
</div>    
</div>
      <script>
          //get modal
          var Testmodal = document.getElementById('TheModalTest');
          //get button that opens modal
          //var modalbtn = document.getElementById('modalbtn');
          var modalbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('modalBtn');

          console.log("Length: " + modalbtn.length);
          //Open modal when btn click
            for (var i = 0; i < modalbtn.length+1; i++ ) {
                console.log("I IS: " + i);

                modalbtn[i].onclick = function(){
                    console.log("MODAL IS: " + modalbtn[i]);

                      /// here your go
                      var category = modalbtn[i].getAttribute('data-category');
                      console.log('category',category);


                    Testmodal.style.display = "block";

                }
            }

      </script>
<script>
```

Comment: Doesnt appear to work still. I have updated the post with images for assistance. (Images taken after new code implemented)